# How can I check the version of a Liferay instance?

Tags: liferay

I have several instances of **Liferay Portal** (bundled with Apache Tomcat 5.5.x/6.x) and *I need to know how to check the version of those Liferay instances*.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

As an administrator, go to:

Control Panel -> Configuration -> Server Administration

The version is in the information banner at the top of the "Resources" tab.

[image: Liferay version]

Answer (score 15):

You can also check that information in the console log when starting up the server or checking the the headers of a HTTP request

Comment: This works for me. The HTTP Header looks like this: Liferay-Portal: Liferay Portal Community Edition 6.0.5 CE (Bunyan / Build 6005 / August 16, 2010)

Comment: Works! During server startup: `Starting Liferay Portal Community Edition` **6.1.2** `CE (Paton / Build 6102 / August 2, 2013)`

Answer (score 9):

Look at class `com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.ReleaseInfo` located in `tomcat/common/lib/portal-kernel.jar`. There is a bunch of static methods for this purpose. You will find the following property: `static String version`.

Comment: So I need to decompile this class to check the version of a Liferay instance? Please, don't say _yes_. Is there no file or a simplest solution to achieve this?

Comment: Sorry, either "yes" or "it depends". http://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-14510, will be fixed in the next version. Or, if you're able to load this class you could actually call the static methods.

Comment: Thanks for your voluntary support.

Answer (score 8):

If you can get the database, which is one:

```
select * from Release_;
```

there is a column called `buildNumber`, it can have a value like 6005 or 5203

The other way, with the apache tomcat startup, you will see in the `catalina.out` log file:
Starting Liferay Portal Community Edition 6.0.5 CE (Bunyan / Build 6005 / August 16, 2010)

Answer (score 5):

You can also check Liferay version Using Chrome Web tools 
[image]

Answer (score 4):

In the enterprise edition, in addition to the installed package (Dima's answer) you can update Liferay using service packs. Here is how to know what service pack level you have installed:

```
cd $LIFERAY/patching-tool
./patching-tool.sh info
```

It will show something like this:

```
Loading product and patch information...
Product information:
  * installation type: binary
  * build number: 7010
  * service pack version:
    - available SP version: 5
    - installable SP version: 5
  * patching-tool version: 2.0.6
  * time: 2018-01-31 08:37Z
  * plugins: Demo 201802, Space 1-2 Columns 50/50 Limited, Space 50/50 Width Limited, Space Program, Space Program Theme

Currently installed patches: de-30-7010

Available patches: de-22-7010, de-30-7010

Detailed patch list: 
  [ -] de-22-7010 :: Currently not installed; Won't be installed: de-30 contains the fixes included in this one :: Built for LIFERAY
  [*I] de-30-7010 :: Installed; Will be installed. :: Built for LIFERAY
```

The important line is `Currently installed patches: de-30-7010`.
Then you know that you have Service Pack 30.

Answer (score 0):

In plugins->build.properties.At bottom line of tht file ,we have a property called lp.version 
which contains liferay version as lp.version=6.0.5

Hope it helps!!

Comment: Thanks, but I cannot locate the file `build.properties` in a Liferay instance. My question is related to Liferay instances already running in production environment. I just run a `find -name build.properties` and it didn't produce any results.