# How to know Liferay Portal version?

Tags: liferay

On my Liferay's `Server Administration` page it writes, that it is

```
Liferay Portal Community Edition 6.2.0 CE (Newton / Build 6200 / January 18, 2012)
```

But version 6.2 is not issued yet and first package was dated 11/03/2012

http://sourceforge.net/projects/lportal/files/Liferay%20Portal/

So which version I use?

Comment: Looking at the site, I do see that there is a milestone 6.2 release. Is it possible you've downloaded that version?

Comment: Milestone releases all issued later than 01/18/2012

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I check the version of a Liferay instance?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4555124/how-can-i-check-the-version-of-a-liferay-instance)