# How can I find out what version of Liferay I have 7.0 or 7.1

Tags: liferay-7

trying to find what version of Liferay I have 7.0 or 7.1
how and where to get the version?

Comment: just read the startup logs

Comment: Please go through below thread has plenty options

https://stackoverflow.com/q/4555124/2634547

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I check the version of a Liferay instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4555124/how-can-i-check-the-version-of-a-liferay-instance)

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to Control Panel > Apps > License Manager

[image]